# TestNG download failure

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng, testng-eclipse

I have been trying to install TestNG from the Eclipse Marketplace but getting the below error.

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help?

Error from Eclipse MarketPlace while downloading TestNG:

[image]

Comment: It looks like an eclipse issue which has a strange certificate configuration. Could you retry on a fresh eclipse install?

Comment: cross reference to the similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847549/not-able-to-install-testng-in-eclipse-kepler