# Not able to Install TestNG in Eclipse-Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

When I tried to Install TestNG on my VM (virtual Machine) getting an error 
"Unable to read repository at http://beust.com/eclipse/content.xml."
"peer not authenticated"

I tried many solution available in the net but no luck. 
Can any one please help me to fix this issue.

Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

**Note**: I don't have Admin Privilege on the VM

[image]
Thanks,
Kannan

Comment: Is the virtual machine insatlled on your personal machine or compnay's machine?

Comment: It is company's machine. I get random VM everyday , I use to Install TestNG in the morning and work on it . But all of sudden a week back,I was not able to Install TestNG and the issue is continuing.

Comment: As a workaround, you can download the offline update site archive, then install from that archive: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/blob/master/README.md#update-sites

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

Click updatesites/

Click any version.

copy resulting URL and use that to install testNG

Example: 
Use following in eclipse install software.
https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/updatesites/6.11.0.201703011520/

Answer (score 1):

URL http://beust.com/eclipse/content.xml will forward you to some other location (probably based on your geo location) to site with HTTPS enabled.

This site presented SSL certificate, which is not trusted by your JVM's keystore.

try it!

```
curl -Lv http://beust.com/eclipse/content.xml
```

`Location: https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release//content.xml`

In your screenshot it is notable by other error:

`sun.security.validatorValidatorException : PKIX path building failed`

You can try to use t[his guide to obtain and import site's CA certificate into your JVM's keystore](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html).

**But first I would examine this certificate if it's fake** or even why JVM didn't recognize it (you are running up-to-date java installation, or not ?)

Comment: please elaborate , where do I need to enter those URLs?

Comment: kannan-c, the testng eclipse plugins are hosted on bintray.com, and according to the error message, @rkosegi 's answer should solve your issue, that is importing the bintray CA certificate into the keystore

Comment: along with the article of importing SSL certificate, you can cross reference to this [link](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/19/installing-eclipse-plug-ins-from-an-update-site-with-a-self-signed-certificate/) for how to specify the keystore in eclipse. (Disclaim that I did not try these steps, but I read them, think that they should work, will write down a wiki about this later)

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

Click updatesites/

Click any version.

copy resulting URL and use that to install testNG

Example: 
Use following in eclipse install software.
https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/updatesites/6.11.0.201703011520/

Steps to follow
Click "Help -> Install New Software..." on top level menu
Paste the url https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse/ to Work with: text field and press enter.
Select the plugins
Click "Next" button and accept the license to complete the installation.
Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

the issue should be fixed now, since the update site http://beust.com/eclipse/ redirects to http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/ (non ssl).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below options....
Option 1 : Follow steps in https://www.dev2qa.com/testng-eclipse-plugin/
Option 2 : If using Option 1, TestNG is not reflecting properly in eclipse follow below URL 
https://www.techbeamers.com/install-testng-in-eclipse-ide/
The URL for downloading the Zip file is for version 6.11. If you need a higher version get it downloaded from 
http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/zipped/
6.14.0 version worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, currently TestNG moved to https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/ from https://beust.com/eclipse while adding new software in eclipse

You can use `https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/<TestNG Version>`

Refer to this site for TestNG Version: https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/

I got this reference from https://testng.org/doc/download.html

Answer (score -1):

Just click on the following link

http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

Download the file "compositeArtifacts.xml" by clicking on it

Copy the downloaded file to your eclipse folder(Source location) For eg:- C:\Eclipse\eclipse

Now try again to install TestNG from eclipse, Done