# TestNG Plugin : Unable to read repository... in Eclipse Luna and Mars

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I am trying to install TestNG but I am getting below error:

```
Unable to read repository at http://beust.com/eclipse/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://beust.com/eclipse/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Possibly firewall?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to Install TestNG in Eclipse-Kepler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847549/not-able-to-install-testng-in-eclipse-kepler)